# The constructor HiveContext(JavaSparkContext) is undefined error while create SQLContext object

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-hive

I'm trying to create SQL context object using JavaSparkContext object as it's parameter like:

```
SparkConf sparkConf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Example");
JavaSparkContext sc=new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
SQLContext sqlctx=new HiveContext(sc);
```

Eclipse is throwing an error saying:

```
The constructor HiveContext(JavaSparkContext) is undefined
```

But all examples I have looked up on the internet, including the documentation uses JavaSparkContext as parameter. Am I missing out something?

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you have Spark 2.2 dependency for spark_hive ?

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And if you use Spark 2.2, HiveContext is deprecated I think, you should just only use SparkSession as the entry point for queries and computations :

> **Upgrading From Spark SQL 1.6 to 2.0**
>
> SparkSession is now the new entry
>   point of Spark that replaces the old SQLContext and HiveContext. Note
>   that the old SQLContext and HiveContext are kept for backward
>   compatibility. A new catalog interface is accessible from SparkSession
>   - existing API on databases and tables access such as listTables, createExternalTable, dropTempView, cacheTable are moved here.